# How to align a <td> right and left

Tags: html, html-table, text-align

I am trying to get the Since and 1932 `<td>`'s to be right next to the picture.  Will aligning the "Since" `<td>` right, and the "1932" `<td>` left work?  If so, how would I do it?  I can't seem to get them RIGHT NEXT TO THE PICTURE.  [JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ecshdtoa/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of having the `image width` as `50%` inside the `<td>`
make the `<td>` width as `50%` and img width `100%`

Here is the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ecshdtoa/12/) DEMO

Then, add a `cssclass` to the first column and text-align right, so the `since` will move right next to the image.

Comment: Thank you.  +1. Could you explain WHY I need to do this?

Comment: you have img width as `50%` and its margin as `0 auto;`. Which means that img will be half the width of td and right in the center, which means within that `td` you will have `25%` empty space on the left of the image and `25%` on the right of it, so obviously the other two `td`'s will be a little far away from the image.